# Identify polygons intersected by lines in a different shapefile

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, intersection, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile with lines and a different shapefile with polygons. I want to identify the id (attribute) of the polygons intersected or overlapped by each line, to then make some additional calculations.

I was thinking about finding the number of intersections but that wouldn't give me the information regarding the polygon id.

I think using the intersect tool from QGIS with the id as selected feature could work, but I can't get it working.

I'm using QGIS 2.18.12

Comment: Intersect sounds like the tool you want, what error do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: The problem was that I was using a similar shapefile, but with different data. My mistake. The answer from @ZrSiO4 was what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a subset of polygons i.e a new shapefile with the intersect tool with your polygon layer as **Input Vector Layer** and your lines as **intersect layer**. Save and add the new shapefile to the layer panel. Then you will not need to  select particular ids because all the polygons in the new intersect shapefile will meet the intersect criteria, and those should have the ids you are after.

Comment: Thanks! Wasn't sure about the output file I needed but this works as I expected.